# Extracting specific elements from a character vector

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a character vector

```
a=c("Mom", "mother", "Alex", "Betty", "Prime Minister")
```

I want to extract words starting with "M" only (upper and lower both)

How to do this?

I have tried using `grep()`, `sub()` and other variants of this function but I am not getting it right.

I expect the output to be a character vector of "Mom" and "mother"

Answer (score 2):

```
a[startsWith(toupper(a), "M")]
```

Comment: R is showing that there is no function as startsWith.

Comment: That's strange - `startsWith` is in the `base` package, which is typically loaded on startup. You could try `a[base::startsWith(toupper(a), "M")]`.

Comment: @AyushRastogi I think it's a relatively recent addition so you might have to update your `R`

Comment: `base::startsWith` exists from R.3.3.0

Comment: small improvement: a[startsWith(a, c("m","M"))] (see benchmarks in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Using `stringr`

```
 library(stringr)
   unlist(str_extract_all(a,regex("^M.*",ignore_case = T)))



[1] "Mom"    "mother"
```

Answer (score 2):

plain `grep` will also do just fine

```
grep( "^m", a, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE )
#[1] "Mom"    "mother"
```

**benchmarks**
tom's answer (startsWith) is the winner, but there is some room for improvement (check `startsWith2`'s code)

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  substr = a[substr(a, 1, 1) %in% c("M", "m")],
  grepl = a[grepl("^[Mm]", a)],
  grep = grep( "^m", a, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE ),
  stringr = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(a,regex("^M.*",ignore_case = T))),
  startsWith1 = a[startsWith(toupper(a), "M")],
  startsWith2= a[startsWith(a, c("M", "m"))]
)


# Unit: nanoseconds
#        expr   min      lq     mean median    uq    max neval
#      substr  1808  2411.0  3323.19   3314  3917   8435   100
#       grepl  3916  4218.0  5438.06   4820  6930   8436   100
#        grep  3615  4368.5  5450.10   4820  6929  19582   100
#     stringr 50913 53023.0 55764.10  54529 55132 174432   100
# startsWith1  1506  2109.0  2814.11   2711  3013  17474   100
# startsWith2   602  1205.0  1410.17   1206  1507   3013   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl`, with the pattern `^[Mm]`:

```
a[grepl("^[Mm]", a)]

[1] "Mom"    "mother"
```

Here is what the pattern `^[Mm]` means:

```
^      from the start of the string
[Mm]   match either a lowercase or uppercase letter M
```

The `grepl` function works by just asserting that the input pattern matches at least once, so we don't need to be concerned with the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Please tell me what is this "^[Mm]"

Comment: This is called *regular expressions*. `^` means beginning of string while `[Mm]` is either `M` or `m`.

Comment: `grepl` also have a `ignore.case` parameter that you can set to `TRUE`. I suppose it makes no significant difference in term of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

`substr` is a very tractable base R function:

```
a[substr(a, 1, 1) %in% c("M", "m")]

# [1] "Mom"    "mother"
```

And since you mentioned `sub()` then you *could* do (not necessarily recommended though):

```
a[sub("(.).*", "\\1", a) %in% c("M", "m")]
```